# How to obtain a certain number of Wikipedia URLS with Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm using this Python code to obtain 10000 URLs from Wikipedia:

```
class WikipediaCrawler(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "wikipedia-crawler"
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random']

    def start_requests(self):
        for page_counter in range(0, 10000):
            yield scrapy.Request(url=self.start_urls[0], callback=self.save_url)

        for page_counter in range(0, 10000):
            yield scrapy.Request(url=self.start_urls[page_counter], callback=self.parse)

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = []

        for link in response.css('a::attr(href)'):
            urls.append(link.extract())

        file_name = response.url.split("/")[-1] + '.html'
        file_name = file_name.replace(':', '_')

        with open('crawled/' + file_name, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)

        yield {
            str(response.url):
            {
                'ranking': 5,
                'links': urls
            }
        }

    def save_url(self, response):
        self.start_urls.append(response.url)
```

It doesn't work. It just only process one page.

I'm using the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random URL to obtain a random Wikipedia page, and therefore its URL.

Comment: You've shown us a few class methods, but not the whole class or how the class is initialized/used.  Post your whole code.

Comment: Try print `self.start_urls` after the first loop (probably reduce the range to like 10 though) to see if you are creating a list of start urls or not

Comment: @JohnGordon I've added more code lines.

Comment: @Dan It does not print the value for the counter with `print(page_counter)`.

Comment: Why crawl wikipedia when they provide all the site data as a dump?

Comment: It's a PSET, @jordanm

Comment: You _still_ haven't shown us how the class is initialized/used.

Comment: @JohnGordon, it's all the code I have until now.

Answer (score 1):

You are yielding the same `start_url` i.e. `url=self.start_urls[0]` 10000 ties. I think you should drop you `start_urls` variable and change `start_requests` to be something like:

```
 def start_requests(self):
     for page_counter in range(0, 10000):
         yield scrapy.Request(url='https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random')
```

My understanding from [the docs](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html#scrapy.spiders.Spider.start_requests) is that scrapy will use `start_requests` as a generator instead of `start_urls` as a list.

So internally I guess it does something like

```
starts = start_requests()
parse(next(starts))
```

Answer (score 1):

The `dont_filter=True` argument solves the problem:

https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#request-objects

> `dont_filter` (*boolean*) – indicates that this request should not be
>   filtered by the scheduler. This is used when you want to perform an
>   identical request multiple times, to ignore the duplicates filter. Use
>   it with care, or you will get into crawling loops. Default to `False`.

Code updated:

```
import crapy    


class WikipediaCrawler(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "wikipedia-crawler"
    start_urls = ['https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Random']

    def start_requests(self):

        for page_counter in range(0, 10000):
            yield scrapy.Request(url=self.start_urls[0], callback=self.parse, dont_filter=True)

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = []

        for link in response.css('a::attr(href)'):
            urls.append(link.extract())

        file_name = response.url.split("/")[-1] + '.html'
        file_name = file_name.replace(':', '_')

        with open('crawled/' + file_name, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(response.body)

        yield {
            str(response.url):
            {
                'ranking': 5,
                'links': urls
            }
        }
```